# TeamCity CI integration between local projects

Tags: teamcity, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have two projects A,B with their own build chains defined in their local `.teamcity` folders. In addition, A contains a dependency on B which I want to test. How do I set up a build chain that incorporates both of these individual builds such that, when B changes I test integration with A's master branch? I imagine I would first set up a second VCS root in B directed at the master branch of A such that the project structure on the agent looks as follows:

```
root
|-- A
|   `-- .teamcity
|       |-- settings.kts
|       `-- /kotlin_code
`-- B
    `-- .teamcity
        |-- settings.kts
        `-- /kotlin_code
```

But I have no idea how to automatically combine project settings from A into the B build chain. I perhaps could jerry-rig some checkout rule `+:A/.teamcity/kotlin_code => B/.teamcity/kotlin_code_A` and pick this up in B but this seems rather inelegant. I could also place all teamcity configuration in a separate repo, but then I lose revision control between A's codebase and its teamcity configuration. Is there a better solution? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I have found is to define a finish build trigger that starts when the previous build completes and send a reverse dependency back through the  build chain to allowing builds to be customized.

Answer (score 0):

https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004237439-Re-use-build-configuration-in-multiple-build-chains

The answer here recommends creating a template under root that encapsulates most of the functionality of B and from this generating separate build chains in A,B. I am not sure this is the most elegant solution, however, so I will leave the question open.